# How can I understand the this part of Freebase?

Tags: wikipedia-api, freebase, freebase-acre

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzw2j.png)

**"(m/0m48smv)"** Based on my knowledge, this should response **page title** from Wikipedia which has a specific id. How can I know the page title?

Answer (score 0):

**m/0m48smv** is the identifier of an entry in the former Freebase database.

The entry has the name "!" and types "relase track" and "topic". 
While some Freebase entries have an associated Wikipedia artice, this is missing for the m/0m48smv entry.

Comment: Thanks. I  want to get the Wikipedia article title and its type in Freebase. Do you have anything helpful with that?

Comment: As Freebase is shut down for over 4 years, there aren't many ways left to access the data. You could either download there last dump from https://developers.google.com/freebase/ or use for example https://tools.wmflabs.org/freebase/. But as I wrote in the answer, not all Freebase entries have an associated Wikipedia article. If you are not forced to use Freebase, I suggest to use any of the successor of Freebase.